# Remove slf4j from gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, slf4j

I have created one gradle plugin. And build.gradle file for it look like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
apply plugin: 'maven'

group 'test.plugin'
version '9.0'

sourceCompatibility = 11.0


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
}
```

When I am trying to apply this plugin into my another project Unit tests are failing because of the following error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLogger cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger (org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLogger and ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

and the plugin I created have the slf4j as well because of the gradle. I need to exclude the slf4j from my plugin. I am not able to find any useful answers on google.